# How many cores/cpus do I actually have?

Tags: windows-8.1, cpu, task-manager

I am confused about what Task Manager is telling me:

[image]

Does this mean that my system has 1 CPU with 4 cores and each of these cores is hyper-threaded?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you think it is: 1 CPU with 4 cores and each core is hyper-threaded.

Comment: @GiantTree Does each individual core become faster if I disable hyper-threading?

Comment: I suggest you try it for yourself. Multiple sources on the internet show that enabling hyper threading improves overall performance for applications that are multi-threaded or for multi-tasking, while it *is* possible that one single-threaded application might see a performance improvement when hyper-threading is disabled.

Comment: "Does this mean that my system has 1 CPU with 4 cores and each of these cores is hyper-threaded?" - Provide the exact CPU you have so I can provide a better answer.

Comment: @Ramhound The CPU is Intel Core i7-6700 @ 3.40 GHz

Answer (score 0):

> Does each individual core become faster if I disable hyper-threading?

**It does not.**  The overal system performance would be lower though. Disabling Hyperthreading would not make the 4 physical cores run faster, compared to how they run, when Hyperthreading is enabled.

> Does this mean that my system has 1 CPU with 4 cores and each of these
>   cores is hyper-threaded?

It does indeed mean that.

Comment: It will be lower but not cut in half. HT doesn't double the actual cores, only allows using the same core for two threads if they use separate parts of the core.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen is correct.  HT does not double the performance.  The % increase HT gives you varies based on a number of factors.  Rarely, if ever would it ever come close to doubling the performance.  There are even some rare cases where HT can *decrease* performance.